# Application gives build time errors stating window is not defined when trying to access localStorage

Tags: reactjs, next.js, next.js14

I am trying to access localStorage to store some user information but when i try to build my project it throws a few errors namely:

1. Error occurred prerendering page "/dashboard". Read more: https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/prerender-error
   ReferenceError: window is not defined
2. Export encountered errors on following paths:
   /(authenticated)/admin-users/page: /admin-users
   /(authenticated)/change-password/page: /change-password
   /(authenticated)/countries/page: /countries
   /(authenticated)/dashboard/page: /dashboard
   /(authenticated)/feedback/page: /feedback
   /(authenticated)/products/page: /products
   /(authenticated)/user-device-mapping/page: /user-device-mapping
   /(authenticated)/users/page: /users
   /login/page: /login
   /page: /

```
useLocalStorage.ts
import { Dispatch, SetStateAction, useEffect, useState } from "react";

type UseLocalStorageReturn<T> = [T, Dispatch<SetStateAction<T>>];

const useLocalStorage = <T>(
  key: string,
  initialValue?: T
): UseLocalStorageReturn<T> => {
  // Ensure initialValue is never undefined, provide a fallback value if necessary
  const fallbackValue =
    initialValue !== undefined ? initialValue : () => undefined as T;

  const [storedValue, setStoredValue] = useState<T>(() => {
    try {
      const localWindow = typeof window !== "undefined" ? window : null;
      if (localWindow) {
        const item = localWindow.localStorage.getItem(key);
        return item ? JSON.parse(item) : fallbackValue;
      }
    } catch (error) {
      console.error("Error retrieving data from localStorage:", error);
    }
    return fallbackValue;
  });

  useEffect(() => {
    const localWindow = typeof window !== "undefined" ? window : null;
    if (localWindow) {
      try {
        const item = localWindow.localStorage.getItem(key);
        const value = item ? JSON.parse(item) : fallbackValue;
        setStoredValue(value);
      } catch (error) {
        console.error("Error updating localStorage value:", error);
      }
    }
  }, [key, fallbackValue]);

  const setLocalStorageValue: Dispatch<SetStateAction<T>> = (value) => {
    setStoredValue(value);
    const localWindow = typeof window !== "undefined" ? window : null;
    if (localWindow) {
      try {
        localWindow.localStorage.setItem(key, JSON.stringify(value));
      } catch (error) {
        console.error("Error updating localStorage:", error);
      }
    }
  };

  return [storedValue, setLocalStorageValue];
};

export default useLocalStorage;
```

Usage==============================

```
const [userData] = useLocalStorage('userData')
```

Please help me resolve this as soon as possible thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You can use [ready solutions](https://www.npmjs.com/package/use-local-storage-safe)

Or do some changes:

Initial State Setup: The initial state is now set to either initialValue or undefined, avoiding immediate access to localStorage. This change prevents the hook from breaking during server-side rendering or static generation.

Client-side localStorage Access: The useEffect hook is now the sole place where localStorage is accessed. It runs only on the client side, ensuring that your code does not attempt to access localStorage during server-side rendering.

Error Handling: The try-catch blocks remain to handle any errors from accessing or updating localStorage, which is particularly useful for environments where localStorage might be restricted (e.g., in incognito mode or when browser policies block its usage).

```
import { Dispatch, SetStateAction, useEffect, useState } from "react";

type UseLocalStorageReturn<T> = [T, Dispatch<SetStateAction<T>>];

const useLocalStorage = <T>(key: string, initialValue?: T): UseLocalStorageReturn<T> => {
  // Initialize state with initialValue or undefined to prevent server-side access
  const [storedValue, setStoredValue] = useState<T>(() => {
    // Ensure initialValue is never undefined, provide a fallback value if necessary
    return initialValue !== undefined ? initialValue : undefined as T;
  });

  // Only try to access `localStorage` in useEffect to ensure it's client-side
  useEffect(() => {
    try {
      const item = window.localStorage.getItem(key);
      // Only update if the item exists, otherwise keep initialValue
      if (item !== null) {
        setStoredValue(JSON.parse(item));
      }
    } catch (error) {
      console.error("Error retrieving data from localStorage:", error);
    }
  }, [key]);

  const setLocalStorageValue: Dispatch<SetStateAction<T>> = value => {
    try {
      // Perform client-side update of localStorage and state
      const valueToStore = value instanceof Function ? value(storedValue) : value;
      setStoredValue(valueToStore);
      window.localStorage.setItem(key, JSON.stringify(valueToStore));
    } catch (error) {
      console.error("Error updating localStorage:", error);
    }
  };

  return [storedValue, setLocalStorageValue];
};

export default useLocalStorage;
```